# Make ajax call, if not desired result, extract a value, then keep repeating until desired result is reached

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Is there any way for an ajax call to, if a desired result wasn't met, extract a value and keep repeating itself every X seconds (or on user request) until it reaches said desired result?

The response of the call is presented as a json-serialized array. I'd like the ajax call to keep repeating itself until `$status_code` is `1` or the response == `"error_bad_api_call"`.

*snipped old code*

**UPDATE:** (Answer)

**PHP script we're going to call (10% chance to provide expected result)**:

```
<?php

$retArr = array();
$rand = rand(1, 1000);

if($rand < 100)
{
    $retArr["status_code"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($retArr);
}
else
{
    $retArr["status_code"] = 0;
    echo json_encode($retArr);
}

?>
```

**The javascript + html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="include/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="include/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Clean all elements on button click
function dosubmitClean(tries)
{
    document.getElementById("resultsHere").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("tries").innerHTML="";

    dosubmit(tries); //Do actual work
}

function dosubmit(tries)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var resp = xmlhttp.responseText; //Get response
            document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+="resp: "+xmlhttp.responseText+"<br/>"; //Show in event log

            var status_code = $.evalJSON(resp).status_code; //Get status code
            document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+="status_code: "+status_code+"<br/>"; //Show in event log

            document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+="Checking status code <br/>"; //Show in event log
            if(status_code == "1"){
                document.getElementById("resultsHere").innerHTML+="status_code: is one <br/>"; //Show final result
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+="status_code: is one <br/>"; //Show in event log
                document.getElementById("tries").innerHTML="Amount of tries: "+tries+"<br/><br/>Event log:<br/>"; //Show amount of tries
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+="status_code: is NOT one <br/>"; //Show in event log
                tries++; //Tries + 1
                dosubmit(tries,"someval"); //Loop
            }
            document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+="Done checking status code <br/><br/>"; //Show in event log
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","json_repeat_php.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="postDataSubmit" onClick="dosubmitClean(<?php echo 1; ?>);return false;">

<div id="resultsHere"></div>
<div id="tries"></div>
<div id="temp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example Output:

```
status_code: is one
Amount of tries: 2

Event log:
resp: {"status_code":0}
status_code: 0
Checking status code
status_code: is NOT one
Done checking status code

resp: {"status_code":1}
status_code: 1
Checking status code
status_code: is one
Done checking status code
```

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to do that way. What are you trying to reach? If you want keep connection with the browser and server, try to look at Node.js and Socket.io. That's kind of push engine, so there is no need to do such polling as you do. And I still don't get, you want to repeat ajax call on the server side, or to get result from server, and if it's not ok - repeat it?

Comment: To answer your last question, I do indeed want to get the result from the server, and if it's not ok, repeat it. I'd really like to get this to work the way I'm trying to. I imagined it was rather simple at it's core; `Try to get expected value -> expected value not met? -> Try again -> Else -> Done.` I did look at Node.js and Socket.io but they're definitely not what I'm looking for. My system is pretty much done the way it is, I just need to get it to work with ajax, without having a user manually click a refresh button so they can get their desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. You already have your callback function, waiting for the result.

Now instead of returning the result as html as you currently do, return it as JSON, so you can easily evaluate it on clientside.
Include your necessary queueCodes in the `elseif{...}` of your php-code.

This could be something like this (Attention, this is pseudocode only!):

```
your json = { success : 0|1 , resultarray [item,item] /* only if success=1 */ , someMoreInfo : <queueCode> }

if ( success ){
     // populate your html with the resulting items
}
else{
     //perhaps wait some time, then
     // call your ajax function again, with your queuecode as parameter
     dosubmit( json.someMoreInfo );
}
```

and your `dosubmit` function sends the queuecode to your server.

A timeout might be useful, either on the server or client, whatever suits you more.

Additionally, you might want to take a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

**sidenotes:**
using a switch in the elseif branch in your php might be more appropriate. Also, try to avoid writing the `{` on a newline in your javascript-code but rather always write `function(){` or `else{`. This potentially saves you some trouble with javascript compilers trying to evaluate your code.

example:

```
return{
   object
}
// returns the object
```

should be the same, but is not the same as:

```
return // comiler will add a ; after your return, thus your object won't be returned
{
   object
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question tos how the end result (with a simplified script).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it recursively.

```
function send_request() 
{
    // perform ajax here and have a callback 
    // if value from callback indicates not successful call send_request() again
    send_request(); 
    // you may want to keep a count of how many times it fails, if it fails say, more than a set number of times then you can take the appropriate action 
}

send_request();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where the problem is, but if I understood you correctly it's enough fro you to make:

```
function gather(queue) {
    data = $('form#foo').serialize();
    if (typeof queue != 'undefined') {
        data += '&queue=' + queue;
    } else {
        queue = 0;
    }
    $.ajax('/frontend_test.php', data, function(r) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(r);
        if (typeof result.status_code == 'undefined' || result.status_code != 1) {
            gather(++queue);
        } else {
            // Success, do whatever you need to.
        }
    });
```

And using it just by calling... it result wouldn't be reached - it goes to recursive call with incremented queue, first call doesn't need to be with any arguments.

Hope that's exactly what you need.